# Object animator using old view position

Tags: android, animation

I have a simple cardview topCard and want to translate it from the center of a layout to right side and back to the initial place.
Wrote some code using object animator:

```
 ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(topCard, "translationX", topCard.getWidth() + 150);
   objectAnimator.setDuration(1500);
   objectAnimator.start();
   objectAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
     @Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
   ObjectAnimator translationX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(topCard, "translationX",  - (topCard.getWidth() + 150));
   translationX.setDuration(1500);
   translationX.start();
```

So, my view correctly translates to the right side and the second animation move it not to the start place but to the `(start place - (topCard.getWidth() + 150))`.

How can I animate translating view to the right and back to the same position using 2 sequence animations?
Here is wrong result that i have
https://i.imgur.com/8SShfHL.gifv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try putting this in your `onAnimationEnd` instead:

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
   ObjectAnimator translationX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(topCard, "translationX", 
           topCard.getWidth() + 150, - (topCard.getWidth() + 150));
   translationX.setDuration(1500);
   translationX.start();
```

Notice that I added `topCard.getWidth() + 150`, making that the starting position of the `topCard`. According to the [`ObjectAnimator.ofFloat` Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html#ofFloat%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20float...%29):

> Constructs and returns an ObjectAnimator that animates between float values. A single value implies that that value is the one being animated to. **Two values imply starting and ending values.**

Comment: Yes, I also have tried this case and the result the same - 
https://i.imgur.com/8SShfHL.gifv
card does not move to her initial place

Comment: Mmm, try putting `0` intead of `- (topCard.getWidth() + 150)` then, like this: `ObjectAnimator translationX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(topCard, "translationX", 
           topCard.getWidth() + 150, 0);`. I guess the animator is taking the original position for reference when you pass it these values.